# MFC: Call a function from different class for context-menu click instead of having it call its default function?

Tags: c++, mfc, contextmenu, right-click

Let's say that I have a grid class called CListCtrlStyled, which is derived from CWnd, a built in class from MFC.

And let's say that I have a another class called Parent that uses an instance of CListCtrlStyled, and is mapped to a list control. Ex.

```
void Parent::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) 
{ 
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_CONTROL, listCtrl);
}
```

CListCtrlStyled has its own functions and handler as well. It would handle the right-click event in this manner.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListCtrlStyled, CListCtrl) 
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CListCtrlStyled)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(NM_RCLICK, OnRclick)   
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Where OnRclick calls a certain function depending on which context menu option (copy, paste, etc.) is clicked.

I'd like to handle the right-click event in the Parent class without evoking the handler in the instance's class, but I'm not sure how to.

I tried handling like this.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Parent, CDialog) 
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CListCtrlStyled)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_RCLICK, IDC_LIST_CONTROL, &Parent::OnRclick) 
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Although it does handle the right click in the Parent class, it also handles it again in the CListCtrlStyled class.

*Note that CListCtrlStyled is used in other classes as well, so just editing the copy function in this class to accommodate for what I want to do with the Parent class is not an option.*

Ultimately, I want to use the copy function of Parent class instead of the instance's class when I click "Copy" from the right-click context menu.

Perhaps this design is flawed? If there's another design to allow me to do what I said, that I should consider, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You (or somebody else) have designed the `CListCtrlStyled` control the way that it processes the Right Click event first using a `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(NM_RCLICK, OnRclick)` macro. The macro defines `CListCtrlStyled::OnRclick` method as a first handler of the Right Click event. In the handler you can return TRUE or FALSE to allow the parent to process the Right Click event. However, as you correctly noticed the event will be first processed by `CListCtrlStyled` and then be passed to the handler of the `Parent` class.

There is a way to process this event in the `Parent` first, and even block it from processing in the `CListCtrlStyled`. You do this in [PreTranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2.aspx). You process the message before it is dispatched, and if you return TRUE `CListCtrlStyled` will not even know about it. Here is a small code:

```
BOOL Parent::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
  if(pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONUP && pMsg->hwnd == listCtrl.GetSafeHwnd())
  {
     // do something

     // if you want to block the message from later processing then return TRUE.
     // if you want to allow the handlers for NM_RCLICK to also handle the message
     // then comment the line below
     return TRUE;
  }
  return __super::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: This was actually very useful! However, now there's a problem I can't seem to get my hands on figuring out if "copy" have been clicked. I'm very new to MFC. Is there a way?

Comment: do not `return TRUE` from the PreTranslateMessage function (i.e. let it finish to the very last line `return __super::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);`, and you will get your notifications

Comment: BTW, I have updated the answer with a comment in the code block

Comment: I'm still confused. If I comment out TRUE, then both CListCtrlStyled and Parent will handle the NM_RCLICK, right? I only want Parent to handle it, and like you said, PreTranslateMessage does the trick. However, it doesn't tell me whether I clicked "Paste" or "Copy" etc.

Comment: when you click Paste or Copy you are getting the notifications for the menu items. E.g. if your "Copy" item has ID_MENUCOPY resource id then you need to create a `ON_COMMAND(ID_MENUCOPY, OnMenuCopy)
` message map with `OnMenuCopy` method and handle the menu commands here

Comment: Ah, okay. At the moment, there is no resource id for paste, copy, etc. So if I understand you correctly, in the CListCtrlStyled class, I'd have to create these ids, and send them when they're selected?

How I'm figuring out which command is clicked right now is with the CMenu class, and its TrackPopupMenu() function. This returns a command number, and depending on that number, the program will execute Copy, Paste, etc. 

So what you're saying is that along with executing those functions like Copy, I should also SendMessage() the resource id? Then I can handle it in the Parent?

Comment: when you call TrackPopupMenu you create a menu. This menu is created somehow, either using a resource or dyinamically. In the former case find the resource and check the IDs for items.min the latter, check what IDs were used for dynamic items

Comment: I see what you mean now. Let's say I do have a menu item called "ID_MENU_COPY", and it's used in the CListCtrlStyled class. When I run the program, and click "Copy" from the context-menu, then it'll fire a "ID_MENU_COPY" message right?

However, wouldn't this just get fired and handled in the CListCtrlStyled first before getting to Parent? 

I also tried testing it with Parent, and it's not picking up the ID_MENU_COPY event. `ON_COMMAND(ID_MENU_COPY, &Parent::Test)` I'm sorry for all the questions. I'm trying to understand this, and you're being very helpful to not ask.